# How to place div and button inside javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I got a javascript variable(siteContents) i want to add a dynamic div to it with hyper link that pops it up . The dynamic div has dynamic div id and dynamic frame url.The button that activates the dynamic div also got dynamic name and dynamic value.

**could any one show me how i can add both dynamic div and its button to siteContents variable ?**

This is dynamic div that i want to add to my siteContents variable:

```
<div id="mangodiv" style="display:none">
<li>
<iframe src="http://www.mysite.com/?itemid=mango&bgcolor=white" style="border: medium none;" height="300" width="450"></iframe><br>
</li>
</div>
```

This is hyperlink that activates the above dynamic div. I want to add this too my siteContents variable:

```
<li><a href="#" onClick="divwin=dhtmlwindow.open('divbox', 'div', 'mangodiv', 'mango', 'width=450px,height=300px,left=200px,top=150px,resize=1,scrolling=1'); return false"><b>popup div</b></a></li>
```

this is the part that activates the popup div:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="windowfiles/dhtmlwindow.css" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="windowfiles/dhtmlwindow.js">
</script>
</head>
```

current variable:
   var itemName = 'mango'

```
var siteContents = "<li>"
   +"<iframe src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTeUusgzharBX4HTwmQHNZOimpaCGRBx4CLKNJAiLjUVi12VN66' height=200 width=200 style='border: none;'></iframe><br>"
   +"<div class='details'>"
   +"<div class='title'>"
   +"<a href='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTeUusgzharBX4HTwmQHNZOimpaCGRBx4CLKNJAiLjUVi12VN66' target=\"_blank\"'>"+itemName+"</a><br>"
+"</div></div></li>";
 document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML += siteContents;
<ul id="myDiv"></ul>
```

i tried this but all hidden divs shows before even clicking the button!

```
var itemName = 'mango'

    var siteContents = "<li>"
       +"<iframe src='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTeUusgzharBX4HTwmQHNZOimpaCGRBx4CLKNJAiLjUVi12VN66' height=200 width=200 style='border: none;'></iframe><br>"
       +"<div class='details'>"
       +"<div class='title'>"
       +"<a href='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTeUusgzharBX4HTwmQHNZOimpaCGRBx4CLKNJAiLjUVi12VN66' target=\"_blank\"'>"+itemName+"</a><br>"

     += " <div id=\"mangodiv\" style=\"display:none\">";
     += "<li>";
     += "<iframe src=\"http:\/\/www.mysite.com\/?itemid=mango&bgcolor=white\" style=\"border: medium none;\" height=\"300\" width=\"450\"><\/iframe><br>";
     += "<\/li>";
     += "<\/div> ";
    += "<a href=\"#\" onClick=\"divwin=dhtmlwindow.open('divbox', 'div', 'mangodiv', 'mango', 'width=450px,height=300px,left=200px,top=150px,resize=1,scrolling=1'); return false\"><b>popup div<\/b><\/a><\/li>";
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now?

Comment: i updated mypost . I want the hidden div dont show if it is not clicked but for some reason it shows all hidden divs!